# Show the topmost y axis point

Tags: highcharts

In the below jsfiddle graph is being generated taking the high and low values, but due to that the y axis top most point is not being calculated.
http://jsfiddle.net/PrFch/

```
     ` Using this code the graph is being is generated so..
         minPadding:0,
        maxPadding:0,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false`
```

As in the below graph the upper most value for the y-axis is 0.72 whereas the line is going far above that point i.e 0.74. 
How can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set showLastLabel as true http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.showLastLabel